# can stop zooming my page in desktop browser

Tags: php, javascript

how can i stop zooming my web page in desktop browser. or, prevent minimum & maximum zooming. that the page will not zoom in or out after the width & height. Thanks.

Comment: How does this relate to PHP

Comment: Why would you want to restrict accessibility?

Comment: Don't do that.  Users zoom for a reason.  You should fix your page so that it doesn't break on zoom.

Comment: You can't it's a browser feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no way to enforce zooming there is a way to suggest to browsers (supported on some mobile browsers) the initial zoom of your site using a meta viewport header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify user-scalable=0 and maximum-scale=1.0 but not all browsers will obey this directive.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```